# VS2019 remote debugging not work from VMware Workstation virtual serial port named pipe

Tags: visual-studio-2019, virtualbox, remote-debugging, vmware-workstation, minifilter

**Host machine:** Windows 10 Pro install Visual Studio 2019 (included WDK).

**Virtual machine:** Windows 8.1 Pro.

I'm trying to debug driver (mini-filter) from Virtual Machine with Visual Studio 2019, all information will be sent to host machine (real machine).

Everything work fine with VirtualBox, but not work at all with VMware Workstation.

This is a log when it worked with VirtualBox.

```
    Starting New Debugger Session         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.19041.685 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

V-HUY\v-huy (npipe WinIDE_01D7664044A98D54) connected at Mon Jun 21 08:53:45 2021

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.19041.685 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Waiting for pipe \\.\pipe\newpipe
Waiting to reconnect...
Connected to Windows 8.1 9600 x64 target at (Mon Jun 21 09:10:42.992 2021 (UTC + 7:00)), ptr64 TRUE
Kernel Debugger connection established.
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 8.1 Kernel Version 9600 MP (1 procs) Free x64
Built by: 9600.17415.amd64fre.winblue_r4.141028-1500
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`57a81000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`57d5a250
System Uptime: 0 days 0:00:00.038
KDTARGET: Refreshing KD connection
```

Failed with VMware Workstation, it just stopped at the line

```
Waiting to reconnect...
```

I've setup VMware Workstation virtual serial port following but not worked as VirtualBox

```
Named pipe> \\.\pipe\newpipe
This end is the server.
The other end is an application.
Ticked Yield CPU on roll.
```

VMware guide: [https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player-for-Windows/16.0/com.vmware.player.win.using.doc/GUID-70C25BED-6791-4AF2-B530-8030E39ED749.html#:~:text=If%20you%20selected%20Output%20to%20named%20pipe%2C%20configure%20the%20named%20pipe](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player-for-Windows/16.0/com.vmware.player.win.using.doc/GUID-70C25BED-6791-4AF2-B530-8030E39ED749.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20selected%20Output%20to%20named%20pipe%2C%20configure%20the%20named%20pipe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Vmware Workstation worked !!!
Default when I add new serial port, it named **Serial Port 2**, that mean **com2**.
So I have some command line:

```
bcdedit /dbgsettings serial debugport:2 baudrate:115200
```

And with Visual Studio, configed target port: **com2**.

Problem fixed !!